# Using typed optional route parameters in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to define a single state with an optional integer route parameter.

I have defined the following state in my application

```
$stateProvider.state('configuration', {
  stateUrl: '/configuration/{id:int}',
  template: '<div></div>'
});
```

This is working for all routes that have an id e.g. `/configuration/1`, but it does not
work for routes without the id e.g. `/configuration/`.

If I drop the type definition, like the below, then routes **work with or without the id** at the end but I end up with a `string` id rather than a `number`.

```
$stateProvider.state('configuration', {
  stateUrl: '/configuration/:id',
  template: '<div></div>'
});
```

Is it possible to define an optional typed route parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using the `params` option.

```
$stateProvider.state('configuration', {
  stateUrl: '/configuration/{id:int}',
  params: { id: { value: null, squash: true } },
  template: '<div></div>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make parameter optional using '?'

Please try following

```
$stateProvider.state('configuration', {
    stateUrl: '/configuration/:id?',
    template: '<div></div>'
});
```

Comment: But then I would lose the type definition and it would become a string right?

Comment: Yes you will lose definition. It will accept string also.
When ever we use braces '{}' in route parameter we are not allow to use parameter as optional or greedy.
This link may help you -- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: Thanks, but I was after an optional integer parameter. Is there no way to do this? Where in the ui-router docs does it say that `{}` treats parameters differently to `:`?

Comment: I tried same at my end but couldn't succeed. To resolve current situation, create two different Routes Url: '/configuration/{id:int}' and Url: '/configuration/' pointing to same template,controllers and other options.

In doc-- it is stated for regex. Regex required {} braces. After watching this I made my above comment. :) 

Statement from Doc:-Route parameters with regular expressions can't be optional or greedy

Comment: Thanks again. I also appear to have had success with `params` object.